# How can I "ignore" NoReverseMatch in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Is there any way to disable throwing `NoReverseMatch` exceptions from `url` tags in Django templates (just make it silently fail, return an empty string or smth... temporarily, for development, of course)?**

(I'm working on a Django project that is kind of a mess as far as things are organized (bunch of remote-workers, contractors plus the local team with lots of overlapping tasks assigned to different people and even front-end and back-end work tends to get mixed as part of the same task...) and *I really need to just ignore/hide/disable the `NoReverseMatch` thrown by template `url` tags in order to efficiently do my part of the job and not end up doing other peoples' jobs in order to be able to do mine...*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest/quickest would be update django's `url` tag to fail silently.

You can update function definition on `def url(parser, token):` in `<your_django_path>/templatetags/future.py` to have all code in `try ... except` and do not raise exception when there is any.

However, this is quickest hack that I could think of, I'm not sure there is any better solution.

Comment: nice, quick and ugly hack and all I have to do to disable it is rename future.py. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

An alternative is using `{% url ... as var %}`, which doesn't raise the exception ([as explained in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url)), but doesn't render the url inline either.

You'll need to replace this:

```
<a href="{% url somepage %}">
```

with this:

```
{% url somepage as var %}
<a href="{{ var }}">
```

Depending on how many templates you've got to work with, this may or may not be the better solution.